# When I try to sign up for an unused handle, Instagram says it's unavailable

Tags: instagram

I am trying to get a handle for my company, which was previously taken, but now it's listed as "Sorry, this page isn't available" when you visit the user page. However, when I try to sign up for that user, Instagram says it's unavailable.

I know SO probably isn't the best place to ask this, but I cannot find any information about this - so I'm wondering if people here have any insight.

Answer (score 2):

Every since Facebook acquired Instagram, some of the help pages have moved to Facebook's help center. It looks like several people have reported this issue.

See [Instagram won't let me create a username I want but I know it is available?](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=794896970569815)

[image: Instagram wont let me create a username I want but I know it is available]

No one from Facebook/Instagram has responded (yet).

I think your best bet is to follow up on that thread, which is on the Official help and support site for Instagram, and hopefully someone from Instagram will address it in the future.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't think to check the Facebook support site. Great idea.